# How to send Ether programatically everyday? (Centralized)

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, wallets

I am new in the Ethereum programming. I am not trying to create a smart contract. I am trying to write a script on a centralized platform (Nodejs or Python or Php server or even Windows task scheduler) that automatically and daily sends the same previously determined percentage of Ethers. For example, I can program it to send 10% of Ethers to wallet A, 35% to wallet B and 55% to wallet C.

I looked at https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Sending-ether but it still requires a user to input passphrase and it assumes a lot a previous steps that are not mentioned in page. Can someone explain a step by step approach for this goal?

Answer (score 1):

If you already know Python, perhaps it might be fastest/easiest to modify https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum to run a task periodically (such was via a separate thread in the program itself). You can also hack the software to your needs (such as not requiring passphrases for signing transactions).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different libraries available for interacting with the Ethereum blockchain.

I think that the Javascript libraries are the best. [ethereumjs-tx](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx) is a good starting point as regards creating and signing transactions.

All you need to do is write a script which queries the account balance (web3 - `getBalance`), does the maths, creates the transactions, and sends them to the blockchain (web3 - `sendRawTransaction`).

If you are automating the running of the script, you'll need to discern the correct nonce at the time of submission. You will of course need to test your code thoroughly, because if something is incorrect then you could lose your Ether.

Answer (score 0):

There are some desktop based bots which can do repetitive task based on inputs that you pre configure. http://www.botchief.com/ this one I've tried before, but not for sending ether. The site has sample videos as well. Try a simple automation before you do your actual one sending ether between accounts.